# how to check if ES6 static method eists

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, exists

I have an ES6 class with a static method.  From another class, I wish to call that static method, but in some instances, the method may not exist.

how do I check if a static method exists before calling it?

```
class MyClassOne
{
    static myStaticMethod()
    {
        .... do something
    }
}
```

Thanks

```
class MyClassTwo
{
    myFunc()
    {
        if(MyClassOne.myStaticMethod)  <-- what should this be?
            MyClassOne.myStaticMethod;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current code's `MyClassOne.myStaticMethod` should do it, you just need to actually call the function with `()`

Comment: That gives an error if the static method doesn't exist.  `Uncaught TypeError: MyClassOne.myStaticMethod is not a function`

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/dvm1w503/

Comment: @Typhoon101 He means `if (MyClassOne.myStaticMethod)` should work fine

Comment: Ah. my apologies. I put the parentheses after myStaticMethod in the IF container, not in the function call. That works. Thanks for your help

Comment: @CertainPerformance Checking for an actual function might be better than just checking for a truthy value.

Comment: @str Sure, if the class has a possibility of having the property, but the property is not  necessarily a function, though class properties usually are